# Comprimir contenido de carpeta en php

Tags: php, zip

Necesito comprimir el contenido de una carpeta y descargarla a través de un botón de html. Mi problema es que el archivo que baja está vació.

Llamo al código de creacción de zip con un input submit

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="createzip" value="Comprimir archivos para la renta" />
```

El código php es el siguiente:

```
if (isset($_POST['createzip'])) {

  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $filename = 'Para_Renta.zip';
  $dir = "../renta/";
  $dir_open=opendir($dir);


  $files = array();
  while ($current = readdir($dir_open)){
    if( $current != "." && $current != "..") {
      if(is_dir($dir.$current)) {
        //  echo $dir.$current.'/';
      } else {
        //echo $current;
        $files[] = $current;
      }
    }
  }

  if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE){
      exit("cannot open <$filename>\n"); // puedes lanzar una excepción
  }

  // USO TU array $files no verifiqué si lo recogiste correctamente
foreach($files as $file){
    $zip->addfile($dir.$file); // las demás opciones por defecto
}
}
```

ADDICION:

Si a este código le añado los encabezados:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); //OJO
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .urlencode(basename($filename)));
    // header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); comentada en original
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0,
           pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    ob_clean();
    flush(); // para volcar el buffer
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
}
```

El archivo baja vacío, si eliminos o comento el archivo no baja si no que se crea con contenido en la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo php del código.

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Creo que lo lógico sería que primero crees el `zip` y después le metas los archivos. En otras palabras, proba mover las líneas `$filename = 'Renta_J&J.zip';$zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE);` justo debajo de la línea `$zip = new ZipArchive;`

Comment: Hola Marcos,

También lo hice y no ha funcionado. He modificado el código tal y como lo tengo ahora, igual a como me lo has comentado y hace lo mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios problemas de orden en la escritura de tu código [php](/questions/tagged/php) de modo que el archivo resultante queda vacío:

Antes de agregar nada debes crear el objeto zip:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
// Luego de crear el objeto abrir un nuevo archivo zip en el que vas a 
// insertar los archivos a comprimir:
$filename = 'Renta_J_J.zip'; // no uso tu & porque no me gusta usar esos
                             // caracteres en rutas directorios y nombres de 
                             // archivo. Es mala práctica usar caracteres 
                             // especiales para los mismos.
if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n"); // puedes lanzar una excepción
}
// Ahora, con el archivo abierto agregar ...

// USO TU array $files no verifiqué si lo recogiste correctamente
foreach($files as $file){
    $zip->addfile($file); // las demás opciones por defecto
}
// Mensajes opcionales de depuración antes de cerrar el zip
echo "Archivos incluidos: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "estado:" . $zip->status . "\n";
// **OJO si vas a enviar el archivo** las dos líneas anteriores deben
// comentarse pues al hacer echo se envían headers distintos de los
// necesarios para servir el archivo comprimido
$zip->close();
// Ahora sigue el código para hacer algo con el archivo
// ...
```

Espero te sirva. Ten cuidado con el orden.

### Adición a la respuesta para servir el archivo

Para ofrecer el archivo debes comentar los llamados `echo` en el bloque de código anterior y enviarlo. Como usas `readfile($filename)` voy a hacer un par de ajustes a esa parte del código usando parte de una respuesta ofrecida por [Alex V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327934/alex-v) *ver referencia 2*

```
<?php
// código para henviar el archivo:
// COPIA casi exacta del encontrado en referencia 2
// solo se cambia el nombre de la variable empleada:
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); //OJO
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .
            urlencode(basename($filename)));
    // header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); comentada en original
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, 
           pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    ob_clean();
    flush(); // para volcar el buffer
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
}
```

### referencias:

1. [Manual de PHP - zipArchive::addFile](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ziparchive.addfile.php)
2. [respuesta a: How to make PDF file downloadable in HTML link?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8122372/5776496)

Comment: Gracias por contestar. He provado tu código y entendiendo sólo falta apuntar a la carpeta donde están alojados los archivos a comprimir.
$dir = "../renta/";

No entiendo está parte del comentario "// Ahora sigue el código para hacer algo con el archivo" tras el close.

En los echos echo . $zip->numFiles ;
echo  $zip->status;  - el output es. Archivos incluidos: 2 estado:0

No descarga archivo zip por que creo falta las instrucciónes header("Content-type: application/zip");
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); Sin embargo sigue apareciendo vacio el fichero.

Comment: Cierto. El código que te ofrecí es para corregir la creación del archivo zip. No para enviarlo. En **aquí sigue tu código** debes hacerlo. En cuanto a los encabezados, no los incluí, porque sólo me interesaba mostrarte la corrección del proceso de compresión.

Comment: Adicionalmente, Si haces el echo antes de enviar encabezados, los encabezados que envíes no pasarán porque junto con el primer echo ya habrán sido enviados y no corresponderán con el tipo de archivo a descargar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que me doy por vencido.

Finalmente he conseguido comprimir los archivos

```
  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $filename = 'Para_Renta.zip';
  $dir = "../renta/";
  $dir_open=opendir($dir);


  $files = array();
  while ($current = readdir($dir_open)){
    if( $current != "." && $current != "..") {
      if(is_dir($dir.$current)) {
        //  echo $dir.$current.'/';
      } else {
        //echo $current;
        $files[] = $current;
      }
    }
  }

  if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE){
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n"); // puedes lanzar una excepción
  }

  // USO TU array $files no verifiqué si lo recogiste correctamente
  foreach($files as $file){
    $localfile = basename($file);
    $zip->addfile($dir.$file, $localfile); // las demás opciones por defecto
  }

  $zip->close();
```

Dado que no veo forma de bajar el archivo, depués de todo lo leido en foros y páginas, he decidido mover el archivo zip a otra carpeta.

```
$filePath = '../renta/'.$filename;
  rename ($filename,$filePath);
```

Y el proposito es que el p..o archivo lo pueda descargar con un botón input.

````
  if(is_file($filePath)){
    // Define headers
      header("Cache-Control: public");
      header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zip_file");
      header("Content-Type: application/zip");
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

      // Read the file
      readfile($filePath);
      exit;

  } ```

El archivo consigo bajarlo finalmente. Sí le doy doble click al archivo me sale el siguiente error. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Sin embargo al presionar extraen en con el menu contextual lo veo todo.

Puedo decir que lo doy por bueno.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC77W.png
````